Are there still red heifers פרות אדומות in Ethiopia?
Shulchan Orit The Halacha of Ethiopian Jewry states:

In Ethiopia, the synagogue was called masgid or beit mikdas or
yetzulot bayit. People related to the synagogue with awe, as a real
Temple. Villagers lived in huts, but the synagogue in every village
was a stone structure, quite large, stable and respectable. The
building stood out in its form, and could be seen and identified from
afar. In large villages, the synagogue was built in the center of the
village. It could be identified from afar by the red clay pot attached
to a pole in the middle of the roof. My grandfather used to say that
whoever came from afar to participate in the prayer services had great
merit – long distances were not a disadvantage, but rather an
advantage. The synagogue structure was divided into three parts – the
courtyard, the hall, and the kadesta kedusan (kodesh ha-kodashim or
“Holy of Holies”). Only the kohanim entered the Holy of Holies, and
the Orit (Torah scroll) was placed there.
The public gathered in the
hall. There were no chairs in the synagogue. Prayers were conducted
while standing, and lasted many hours. Thus many people carried
walking sticks, on which they leaned when they grew tired of standing,
as in the verse, “Your rod and Your staff, they comfort me” (Psalms
23:4). The synagogue courtyard also served as a gathering place for
sermons, study, offering sacrifices, reading the Torah, and any event
of sacred character. The inside of the synagogue was used for prayer
services only. When praying, the congregants faced Jerusalem. Before
entering the synagogue, congregants removed their shoes in respect for
the sanctity of the site. They spread leaves on the synagogue floor,
so as not to have direct contact with the floor. Inside the Holy of
Holies stood the tevot (ark), and the Orit stood on top. Next to the
Orit were additional garments for the kohanim and two jars – one with
ashes from the parah adumah (red heifer), the other with holy water
for sprinkling on the sacrifices.
Up until the aliyah to Eretz
Yisrael, the Beta Israel had a continuous tradition for the observance
of all the biblical laws of purity and impurity. This included the
laws of impurity relating to tumat hamet, contact with a dead body,
and the means of purifying oneself from it with the ashes of the red
heifer. In Ethiopia, some animals met the biblical qualifications of a
parah adumah. Against this backdrop, we must ask why the rabbinic and
Talmudic tradition testifies that the parah adumah no longer exists.
Was it the intention of the Sages to cease the observance of all laws
of purity and impurity in the wake of the destruction of the Holy
Temple? Perhaps they felt that since the destruction of the Second
Temple ended the use of the parah adumah in Jerusalem, therefore the
practice should be halted everywhere. In Ethiopia, however, the Beta
Israel were careful to observe all laws of purity and impurity as
specified in the Torah.

Are there still red heifers פרות אדומות in Ethiopia today?
If so, has their usage been continuous in Ethiopia?
If not when did it cease?
Shulchan Orit: From Sinai to Ethiopia, Halacha of Ethiopian Jewry

It is doubtful there were ever any red-heifers that halakhah, as it stands within Rabbinic Judaism, would recognize (see Hilkhoth Parah). As this article in Makor Rishon explains:

ההקפדות התלמודיות הרבות בעניין כשרות פרה אדומה לא נהגו שם, וכל פרה
בגוון חום בהיר נחשבה לכשרה
The many strictures regarding the kashruth of the red heifer attested
to in Talmudic literature were not practiced there [in Ethiopia], and
any light-brown cow was considered kosher [to the Beta Israel for this ritual purpose]

R. Menachem Waldman, a well known champion of the Beta Israel, similarly confirms (Mas'a El Shearith Yehude Itiyopia, p. 47):

לצורך היטהרות מטומאת מת הכינו אפר של פרה אדומה שלמעשה הייתה פרה חומה
שנזבחה ונשרפה
For the purpose of purification from impurity imparted by death, they
prepared ash from a red-heifer which in practicality/reality was a
brown cow that was sacrificed and burnt

Whereas the Beta Israel understood a red-heifer to be a fairly common brown-heifer, traditional Rabbinic Judaism understands the red-heifer to be spectacularly uncommon, given the many strictures by which it may be identified. Traditionally only nine are known to have existed (H. Parah 3:):

ותשע פרות אדמות נעשו משנצטוו במצוה זו עד שחרב הבית בשניה. ראשונה עשה
משה רבנו. שניה עשה עזרא. ושבע מעזרא עד חרבן הבית. והעשירית יעשה המלך
המשיח מהרה יגלה אמן כן יהי רצון
Nine red heifers were offered from the time that they were commanded
to fulfill this miswah until the time when the Temple was destroyed a
second time. The first was brought by Moses our teacher. The second
was brought by 'Ezra. Seven others were offered until the destruction
of the Second Temple. And the tenth will be brought by the king
Moshiah; may he speedily be revealed. Amen, so may it be God's will.

Here are some photos showing a Kes with his holy objects, which include a satchel of ash from what they deemed a red-heifer (ibid):


Dr. Steven Kaplan, one of the leading scholars on the origins of the Beta Israel, writes (The Beta Israel (Falasha) in Ethiopia, p. 196, fn. 32):

The Beta Israel laws of social purity known as attenkugn (don't touch
me) are attributed to the fifteenth-century monastic leader Abba Sabra
... Given the tendency in oral traditions to date virtually all
important religious institutions to his time, some caution must be
exercised in dating these laws. It is difficult to discern any period
in which they could have been observed strictly by all Beta Israel.
Indeed, tenant farmers, soldiers, and craftsmen would all have found
them an onerous burden. In all probability such laws represent an
ideal for behavior practiced in reality primarily by only the monastic
clergy.

Given that the evidence for this community's observance of purity laws dates back to the 15th century, it would be hard to characterize their observance as "continuous". In fact it seems that it was a practice that was not really emphasized as much until the 19th c. as a reactionary measure against Christian persecution (coming in contact with Christians was believed by them to impart impurity, thus necessitating purification via the ashes). As for when it ceased, it would seem that (at least according to the abovementioned Makor Rishon article) that the last time a red-heifer (as defined by Ethiopian custom) was slaughtered was in 1952:

הפרה האדומה האחרונה של 'ביתא ישראל' נשחטה באתיופיה בשנת 1952
The last red-heifer to be slaughtered by the Beta Israel in Ethiopia was in 1952

The practice seems to have been disbanded as a result of the wars in Ethiopia and later absorption of the community by Israel.
